# Auto confirm an apt prompt in Bash

Tags: bash, apt

I am trying to make a bash script that will auto confirm the apt prompt when installing a package. 
Here is what I try to auto confirm, and yes, I already tried "-y".

```
sudo apt install matchbox-keyboard -y
```

My rasp is in french and it keeps telling me that "-y" isn't recognized. Of course, since my rasp is in french, the prompt gets confirmed when I write "O" instead of "Y", but since I want my script to work with every language, I am looking for a way to use "-y" even on a french machine.

Does anyone of you know how to force the english confirm on a foreign language machine ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Don't the options have to come before the subcommands? According to the [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt-get.8.en.html), the synopsis is `apt -y install ...`. I'd be surprised if the language setting affects the `y`/`n` prompt interpretation.

Comment: Or maybe (can't test currently), the `apt` options aren't passed through to `apt-get` and you need to use `apt-get` directly.

Comment: Okay, it might (surely is) my bad there, didn't thought I could misplace the `-y`. Just went to check in a script I took inspiration from and there was written `apt-get install -y [package]`. Thought a bash script worked as a terminal with the `-y`at the end of the command. Gonna ty is asap, thanks or the answer !

Comment: Where the command is run from doesn't affect how `apt` would  interpret the `-y` option.

Comment: if the previous suggestion doesnt work try `sudo export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` and then your apt install